# How to get y coordinate of line chart fl_chart

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

I would like to ask how can I display the LineBarSpot on the chart independent of the defined spots. For example, if I have 4 spots, and I want to find out the value of y on any part of the graph, I simply click on the given part of the graph and a bar with the given value rounded to 2 decimal places will appear. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried to do it somehow via the touchCallBack function, but to no avail. Any help would be great, thanks in advance for your reply. :))

My code:

```dart
LineChartData data() {
    return LineChartData(
      borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
      gridData: FlGridData(
        show: true,
        drawVerticalLine: false,
        horizontalInterval: widget.lineInterval,
        getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return FlLine(
            color: ColorsTheme.lightGray,
            strokeWidth: 1,
          );
        },
      ),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        show: true,
        rightTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        topTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            reservedSize: 25,
            interval: 1,
            getTitlesWidget: titles,
          ),
        ),
        leftTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      minX: 0,
      maxX: 4,
      minY: 0,
      maxY: widget.maxY,
      lineTouchData: LineTouchData(
        touchTooltipData: LineTouchTooltipData(
          tooltipBgColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
          tooltipBorder: const BorderSide(
            color: ColorsTheme.darkGray,
          ),
          tooltipPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 15,
            vertical: 4,
          ),
          tooltipRoundedRadius: 30,
          getTooltipItems: (touchedSpots) {
            return touchedSpots.map((barSpot) {
              dynamic spot;
              widget.showDecimals ? spot = barSpot.y : spot = barSpot.y.toInt();
              return LineTooltipItem(
                "$spot",
                const TextStyle(
                    color: ColorsTheme.text, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        ),
      ),
      lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(
          spots: widget.points,
          isCurved: true,
          color: ColorsTheme.mainBlue,
          barWidth: 3,
          isStrokeCapRound: true,
          dotData: FlDotData(
            show: false,
          ),
          show: true,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

I tried to display the value using the nearest number or offset, but it was always inaccurate.